# Analyzing data from a file and output them in a dictionary in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a function called `average_by_section: (file, str) -> float`

The first parameter is an open file of marks. Each line represents a single student and consists of a student number, a name, a section code and a grade, all separated by whitespace.

which for example looks like this:

```
987654322    Xu             Carolyn         L0101   19.5
233432555    Jones          Billy Andrew    L5101   16.0
555432345    Patel          Amrit           L0101   13.5
```

Return the average mark for all students in that section, or return `None` if the section code does not appear in the marks file for any students.

The hints I got are:

- Hint: Notice that the number of names per student varies.
- Hint: Use `rstrip()` to get rid of extraneous whitespace at the end of the lines.
- Hint: For testing this function, write a helper function that opens and closes the marks file and calls `average_by_section` in between.

I am now up to spiting the element in the line of the file:

```
def average_by_section(marks, section):
    dic = {}
    for line in marks:
        wordlist = line.split()
```

And I don't know what to do next...

I need some instruction/guide to finish this function.

How would you write this function?

Comment: The number of names per student varies but once you split the line, you can see that the first element of the list will always be the roll number and the last two elements will always be section code and grade. Combine the remaining elements of the list.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it helped me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this as next line:

```
(studentNumber, *names, sectionCode, grade) = wordlist
```

It's a nice new Python3 feature with that `*` in that assignment :)

And concerning that open/close of the file:  You're using a high-level language which eases this part dramatically:

```
with open('/path/to/marks/file.txt') as marks:
    print average_by_section(marks, section)
```

That's it.  The `with` does all the opening and closing for you.